# Name of the act of borrowing linguistic concepts from different languages

Tags: terminology, etymology, borrowing, idiomaticity

What is the term for concepts that got translated from one language or another?

I've heard this term in a conversation about Czech Anglicisms such like: *"Mějte hezký den."* - the literal version of the English phrase "Have a nice day."* which wasn't really used in Czechia in the past.

It may include just randomly shared concepts as well. For example *a bit* – a small amount [originally meant](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bit) a "piece bitten off". I guess the same applies for Czech *kus*.

Comment: In general, these are simply loan words; when it's about whole phrases or idioms, you might correspondingly call them loan phrases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concept is actually pairing of "what it refers to" (meaning) and a word, so "cow" refers to, well, you know what, and "gabba" (a word of North Saami) refers to "white reindeer", where we use a phrase since we have no reason to have specifically identifies a concept "Whitereindeer". A better way of putting it is in terms of "expressions", i.e. some phrase in one language is used for some purpose, like "you're welcome". Your example is an example of a "calque", which is a word for word loan translation.

Comment: That's what I meant!